# D3.js: calculate width of bars in time scale with changing range?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a D3 bar chart with a time scale on the x-axis. The range of the x-axis can vary.

How can I specify the correct width for the bars on the bar chart? I've seen people use `rangeBands` for ordinal scales, but I'm not sure how to do this with a time scale.

Here is my code:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
[...]

// After new data has been fetched, update the domain of x...
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
d3.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);

// ... and draw bars for chart
var bars = svg.selectAll(".air_used")
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.date; });

bars.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.air_used); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.air_used); })
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.attr("width", 20) // ??
```

What should I put on the last line, in place of 20?

UPDATE: JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aWJtJ/2/

Answer (score 35):

There's no function to get the width, but you can calculate it quite easily:

```
.attr("width", width/data.length);
```

You might want to subtract a small amount from that if you don't want the bars to touch. You would also need to adjust the `x` position accordingly, e.g.

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date) - (width/data.length)/2; })
.attr("width", width/data.length);
```

To get the ticks to align properly, you'll also need to adjust the range of the x axis scale because the first tick will be placed at the first value:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([width/data.length/2, width-width/data.length/2]);
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aWJtJ/8/).

Comment: Thanks! The first suggestion is almost there, but the `x` function seems to be inserting some padding between bars: http://jsfiddle.net/aWJtJ/1/ If I try using the second function, again, it's almost right but it's still inserting padding between the bars: http://jsfiddle.net/aWJtJ/2/ - I don't understand why the `x` function can tell my code where the `x` position of the bars should be, but can't tell where the width should be, given that it obviously does have a firm idea of what the width should be.

Comment: Ok, you need actually a bit more -- in particular, you need to adjust the range because the first tick will be at the first value (see edited answer). As for why D3 doesn't tell you the width itself, I have no idea -- you could open a feature request.

Answer (score 4):

Even though I agree with Scott that a bar chart is meant to be used with ordinal or categorical data on x axis, I guess the question is more about a convenience of drawing a time axis. As `d3.time.scale` does a really good job with help of `d3.time.format.multi` of drawing time axis of various duration (hours, days, months, etc.) and its ticks, it could be a good idea to combine `d3.time.scale` for an axis, and `d3.scale.ordinal` for a band width calculation.

The snippet below is inspired by [the discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/7GsDmnB4kdE) in D3 Google Group about the topic. The unit for ordinal scale is a day.

```js
function prepare(data)
{
  var dateParse = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d');
  data.forEach(function(v)
  {
    v.date = dateParse.parse(v.date);
  });

  var dateValueMap = data.reduce(function(r, v)
  {
    r[v.date.toISOString()] = v.value;
    return r;
  }, {});

  var dateExtent = d3.extent(data.map(function(v)
  {
    return v.date;
  }));

  // make data have each date within the extent
  var fullDayRange = d3.time.day.range(
    dateExtent[0], 
    d3.time.day.offset(dateExtent[1], 1)
  );
  fullDayRange.forEach(function(date)
  {
    if(!(date.toISOString() in dateValueMap))
    {
      data.push({
        'date'  : date,
        'value' : 0
      });
    }
  });

  data = data.sort(function(a, b)
  {
    return a.date - b.date;
  });

  return data;
}

function draw(data)
{
  var margin = {
    'top'    : 10, 
    'right'  : 20, 
    'bottom' : 20, 
    'left'   : 60
  };
  var size = {
    'width'  : 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    'height' : 180 - margin.top - margin.bottom
  };

  var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
    .attr('width',  '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%')
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  var dates = data.map(function(v)
  {
    return v.date;
  });
  var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, size.width])
    .domain(d3.extent(dates));

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([size.height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(v)
    {
      return v.value;
    }))]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient('bottom');

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left');

  var barWidth = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(dates)
    .rangeRoundBands(x.range(), 0.1)
    .rangeBand(); 

  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + barWidth / 2 + ',' + size.height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis)
    .append('text')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
    .attr('y', 6)
    .attr('dy', '.71em')
    .style('text-anchor', 'end')
    .text('Amount');

  svg.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function(d) 
    { 
      return x(d.date); 
    })
    .attr('width', barWidth)
    .attr('y', function(d) 
    { 
      return y(d.value); 
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) 
    { 
      return size.height - y(d.value); 
    });
}

function getData()
{
  return [
    {'date': '2014-01-31', 'value': 5261.38}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-02', 'value': 7460.23}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-03', 'value': 8553.39}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-04', 'value': 3897.18}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-05', 'value': 2822.22}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-06', 'value': 6762.49}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-07', 'value': 8624.56}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-08', 'value': 7870.35}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-09', 'value': 7991.43}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-10', 'value': 9947.14}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-11', 'value': 6539.75}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-12', 'value': 2487.3}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-15', 'value': 3517.38}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-16', 'value': 1919.08}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-19', 'value': 1764.8}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-20', 'value': 5607.57}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-21', 'value': 7148.87}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-22', 'value': 5496.45}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-23', 'value': 296.89}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-24', 'value': 1578.59}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-26', 'value': 1763.16}, 
    {'date': '2014-02-27', 'value': 8622.26},
    {'date': '2014-02-28', 'value': 7298.99}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-01', 'value': 3014.06}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-05', 'value': 6971.12}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-06', 'value': 2949.03}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-07', 'value': 8512.96}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-09', 'value': 7734.72}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-10', 'value': 6703.21}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-11', 'value': 9798.07}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-12', 'value': 6541.8}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-13', 'value': 915.44}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-14', 'value': 9570.82}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-16', 'value': 6459.17}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-17', 'value': 9389.62},
    {'date': '2014-03-18', 'value': 6216.9}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-19', 'value': 4433.5}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-20', 'value': 9017.23},
    {'date': '2014-03-23', 'value': 2828.45},
    {'date': '2014-03-24', 'value': 63.29}, 
    {'date': '2014-03-25', 'value': 3855.02},
    {'date': '2014-03-26', 'value': 4203.06},
    {'date': '2014-03-27', 'value': 3132.32}
  ];
}

draw(prepare(getData()));
```

```css
#chart {
  width  : 600px;
  height : 180px;
}
.bar {
  fill : steelblue;
}

.axis {
  font : 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill            : none;
  stroke          : #000;
  shape-rendering : crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='chart'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem when changing zoom levels on a bar chart with a time series based x-axis and found two solutions.

1) Create a companion ordinal scale to help calculate the widths.(a pain)

2) The time-series x axis is your friend - use it to calculate the width.

If you want your bar to always be a "month" wide, irrespective of zoom level in you can do something like this. Im assuming d.date is available in the data.

```
 svg.selectAll(".air_used").attr("width", function(d.date) {
    var next = d3.time.month.offset(d.date, 1);
    return (x(next)- x(d));
  });
```

This works well because it works for every zoom scale, and you just need to call this function at the end of your on "zoom" handler ie .on("zoom", zoomed); 
The x axis will usually have been adjusted at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Since time scales are continuous, there can be many ideas of what a "correct" bar width is.  If your data points are very granular and unevenly distributed, you may want to use a thin bar of fixed width to minimize overlaps.  If you know something about your expected data values ahead of time and they are uniform granularity, you can do something like what @LarsKotthoff to space them out evenly.

One thing to consider is whether what you actually want a time scale at all.  Bars are generally used to represent categorical values, not points on a continuous scale.  Maybe an ordinal scale with the domain derived from a date range is actually want you want.  In that case you could use rangeBands as per your original post.

Not saying it is wrong to do what you're doing.  Just food for thought.

Comment: Thanks! I do need to use a time scale because I want to use time formats for ticks: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_tickFormat

Comment: If formatting is the only reason and you have a known number of discrete values you can format the dates as strings before you pass them into the ordinal scale.  Of course, you need to be careful to format all date data into strings in the identical way before scaling, probably with a shared getter function or something. Or convert data to strings early on. It really depends whether you need the semantics of a time data type or not.

Comment: BTW, you can use D3's time parser and formatter independent of any scale: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting

Comment: Thanks - I wonder if that's the best approach - format the strings first, and then use an ordinal scale. I'll try that.