# D3.js: Uniformly spaced bars on time scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a simple bar chart with evenly spaced bars on time scale in x-axis but unsuccessful even with the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835053/d3-js-calculate-width-of-bars-in-time-scale-with-changing-range)

I am getting overlaps in the bars and unevenly spaced bars. Part of my code as below:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([width/data.length/2, width-width/data.length/2]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

bars.transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date) - Math.floor(width/data.length/2); })
    .attr("width", Math.floor(width / data.length))
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.c); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.c);});

bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "air_used")
    .attr("width", Math.floor(width / data.length))
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date) - Math.floor((width/data.length)/2); })
    .attr("y", height)
    .attr("height", 0)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.c); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.c);});
```

JSFiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/vivekratnavel/v7rx8ku9/2/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you date/times overlap within the width of the bar, the only solution is to vary the barwidth for each or make it small enough for all of them that there's no overlap... Is that what you are after?

Comment: @Mark I don't know if I understood your question completely, but what I am looking for is evenly spaced bars similar to the ones found in crossfilter ( http://square.github.io/crossfilter/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set hours to 0hrs:0min:0sec before scaling the time on x-axis.

http://jsfiddle.net/hnj30m4j/

```
bars.transition().duration(1000)
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date.setHours(0,0,0))  - Math.floor(width/data.length/2); })
.attr("width", Math.floor(width / data.length))
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.c); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.c);});

bars.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "air_used")
.attr("width", Math.floor(width / data.length))
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date.setHours(0,0,0)) - Math.floor((width/data.length)/2); })
.attr("y", height)
.attr("height", 0)
.transition().duration(1000)
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.c); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.c);});
```